# Android - GCM notifications of app_1 accessible from app_2

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to ask you how to get **GCM notification from another app**. If you know AirDroid or Desktop Notification - these applications somehow (I don't know how) extract notifications (even GCM ones) to desktop.

**In my customized app_2** I would like to **extract notification from app_1** (but I cannot change app_1, I supposed that app_1 is completed) and these extracted data would be represented for example by text/content of the notification. Is it possible at all? I actually managed this with "normal" notifications but I failed with GCM ones.

I guess that app_1 has a broadcast receiver and a service. I would like to have app_2 that runs on the background and checks GCM notifications by app_1.

I would be satisfied if I have an **example code with receiving GCM notification of app_1 with packagename_1.** I have not found this specific case on Google if I am not generally wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are looking for is [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html).

Comment: I guess not because I implemented it by [this](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/11/reading-notification-using-notificationlistenerservice.html) and it was getting "not GCM" notifications but it could not catch the GCM ones.